# Raspberry Pi's reaction to 7.2 Volts applied to a GPIO pin?

Tags: cpu, voltage

I was using a **Raspberry Pi 3 model B** in a project. The Pi was connecting to a web socket and receiving data from the user on a PC or whatever device connected to the same socket.

It was fine at first. But I mistakenly touched **-for a moment-** a GPIO pin -that was pulsing- to a **7.2v battery's positive that had its ground connected to the Pi's ground.**

I was controlling it using SSH, but suddenly the terminal stopped working (without telling that the Pi disconnected; it always tells when Pi disconnects) and **Pi heated up**. I removed all the pins connected and unplugged the charger.

When I plugged the charger again, the Red LED lit faintly and the CPU heated and became untouchable in less than a second.

**Is there any way for the Pi to work again?**

Comment: Sorry to say,  i think its dead....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Take it on the bright side.

**You have learned one thing never to do to a Raspberry Pi.**